# Svelte (not SvelteKit) Add CORS "allow origin ..." in client's HTTP Header

Tags: node.js, cors, http-headers, svelte

So I keep having the error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/<...>' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I would like to know how to add the field `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`in the HTTP Header for a Svelte website. I precise it again, I am on Svelte, not on SvelteKit (Foud lots of solution for SvelteKit)
I would have think it could be added in the `main.ts` but I get an error if I do so :

```js
const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'my APP'
    },
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' // or, e.g. replacing * by http://localhost:8000
    }
});
```

And I get the error:

```
Argument of type '{ target: HTMLElement; props: { name: string; }; headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Svelte2TsxComponentConstructorParameters<any>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'headers' does not exist in type 'Svelte2TsxComponentConstructorParameters<any>'.ts(2345)
```

So, where can I set that ?

NB. I also [found this](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/) about CORS with NodeJS, can I use it with Svelte, or it will not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS has nothing to do with Svelte; the server has to allow access from another origin, not the client. So whatever is serving `http://localhost:8000` has to set the headers. How exactly that is done depends on the type of server.

The example that can be downloaded from the REPL uses [`sirv-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sirv-cli) to preview the compiled Svelte files. To make Sirv return requests with CORS headers, the flag `-c` can be used which just needs to be added to the `start` script in `package.json`.

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear -c"
  },
}
```

Comment: OK, but then, if it's like the default Svelte app, the server is Nodejs, no?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default Svelte app". You only need Node if you use SSR, otherwise any server type can be used. And even if you use Node, there are many ways of serving requests, either directly or using one of the many abstractions libraries like `express`  or just a simple file server like `http-server`. You can even use Svelte without any server using a desktop application framework like `electron` or `tauri`.

Comment: Yes there is. 1. download code from a REPL example 2. `npm install` 3. `npm run dev --`

Comment: That is just for quickly previewing examples and not something you would use to run the final application. You can look at the `package.json` and see what the commands do. `dev` just runs Rollup and the Rollup config executes the `start` script which uses `sirv` (from `sirv-cli`) to start an HTTP server for preview. You just have to add the flag `-c` to the start script to add CORS headers.

Comment: Ah good, could you edit your answer to add those details please I think that is what I am looking for 

Comment: Answer is edited.

Comment: Super, thanks, I will validate it, as soon as I test it!  And BTW, Whats the best server for prod? or what would be your choice?

Comment: Depends on your server logic needs. `express` is e.g. good but pretty bare bones on its own; it is meant to be very extensible though. I have some projects that use [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) with `express` under the hood, which adds some more functionality like interception of requests, piping inputs and dependency injection. There is a tradeoff to be made as this incurs some more boilerplate to set everything up and one needs to familiarize oneself with the whole system.

Comment: So I edited the start script as you mentionned : `"start": "sirv public --no-clear -c",` but I still see the error and I can see in the response header when retrieving the main page  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` I don't understand what can be wrong then...
I am using FastAPI on the other side, could it be this ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to add the headers to the server that you request data from. I might have mixed up the port, though. You can just search for whatever you are using together with "set headers" and you most likely will easily find how to do it. For FastAPI [this comes up](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/).